# Если не равно 1 или не равно 2

Tags: python, python-3.x

В Java помню что или это `&`...
А как сделать в Python что в цикле:

```
while number != 1 или 2 или 3:
print("Не то")
input("введи")
```

И как сделать чтобы оно повторялось, пока не будет введено либо 1, либо 2, либо 3?

Comment: `while not number in range(1,4)`

Comment: [Чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ или отметьте его как решение.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 5):

Если ожидается ввод числа, тогда можно так:

```py
guesses = [1, 2, 3]
number = int(input('Введите число: '))

while not number in guesses:
    print("Не то...")
    number = int(input('Введите число: '))

print("Оно!")
```

Comment: место `or` надо `and`

Comment: ``number != 1 or number != 2 or number != 3`` - любое число удовлетворяет этому условию.

Answer (score 3):

можно так:

```
while 1 <= number <= 3:
```

Comment: Это обратное условие.